Get Image from Bind Mount (Thymeleaf, Spring, Docker)
I'm trying to get images from Bind Mount in Docker
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysqldb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=recreation_db
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
    volumes:
      - mysqldb_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kursach6sem

  kursach6sem:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: kursach6sem
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysqldb
    networks:
      - kursach6sem

volumes:
  mysqldb_data:

networks:
  kursach6sem:

application.yml
spring:
  web:
    resources:
      static-locations: classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,/app/uploads/
      add-mappings: true

Thymeleaf image:
                <img th:src="@{file:///app/uploads/${object.getId()}/${object.getMainPhoto()}}"
                     th:alt="${object.getName()}"/>

I can see my image in app->uploads->id->name.img. But can't get it from Thymeleaf
